# restructuredtext table and embedded substitutions

Tags: restructuredtext

I would like to be able to do something like this with restructuredtext tables. Any idea if this is possible? Thanks!

```
.. |code1| literalinclude:: code1.cpp
.. |img1| image:: https://example.com/img1


======    =====
code      image
======    =====
|code1|   |img1|
=====     =====
```

Comment: No. Substitutions will not interpolate a directive, including `literalinclude`.

Comment: Ok thank you. Would this be a good thing for the language?

Answer (score 0):

You can use body elements inside a table cell:

```
======================  ==================================
code                    image
======================  ==================================
.. include:: code1.cpp  ..image:: https://example.com/img1
======================  ==================================
```

The [table directive](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#table) allows controling the column width independent of
the width of the columns in the source code.